# CSS border property not getting reflected on svg text

Tags: css, svg

The border property not getting applied on SVG text. I do not want to use the outline property as it does not have support to give different colour on different sides, neither do I want to use additional svg elements like rect or path as it would make my task more complicated as a whole. Please guide how can I apply border css on SVG text element.

```html
<body>
  <style>
    #abc {
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
  </style>
  <svg height="100" width="200">
      <text x="10" y="25" fill="red" id="abc">I love SVG!</text>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>

</body>
```

Comment: have you tried `stroke` attribute of SVG element?

Comment: and why using SVG to write a simple text?

Comment: @Temani Afif, It is bigger project than just display simple text, which requires it, I have just posted my problem statement using the bare minimum code to explain my problem statement.

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani I have not downvoted, but yes I already specified in the question that I cant use outline property as it do not support giving different colours on different sides.

Comment: SVG text elements do not support the border property per the SVG specification.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
  <style>
    #abc {
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
  </style>
  <svg height="40" width="100" id="abc">
      <text x="10" y="25" fill="red" >I love SVG!</text>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>

</body>
```

Comment: I want to have border on individual text element and not on parent svg element. As in my code there would come several text element within 1 parent svg element.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.abc { height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 88px;}
</style>
<svg class="abc">
  <text x="5" y="18" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```